# Get stage in ActionScript-3 without a DisplayObject?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, stage

How can I get a reference to my stage **without** having a Sprite/DisplayObject that is added to the stage already ?

---

***More info:** I have a static class that is a utility class and I want it to initialize in static class constructor but I also need the reference to the stage.*

```
public class UtilClass
{
    trace("init: " + stage);
}
```

*First thing that is called in my AS-3 apps is the constructor of my main Sprite/DisplayObject and it has access to the stage. So the stage exists at that point. **Then** I call utility methods of my `UtilClass`. Now I want it to initialize by itself on the first use (when stage is already in existance).*
**I want to know if stage object can be accessed from anywhere without being initialized from outside of the utility class.**

**Edit:**

```
public class SimpleSprite extends Sprite
{
    public static var aaa:int = 12;

    public static function test():void
    {
        trace("here I am");
    }

    trace(aaa, Capabilities.screenResolutionX+", "+Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
    test();
}
```

Comment: You need to pass it on to your class I think. Your class needs methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stage reference is available in your `MainTimeline` or `Main` instance, depending on platform. You can add code there to pass that reference to other classes should you need it. The class should have a method (static, in your case) that'll accept a `Stage` parameter and store it somewhere inside the class.

```
public class UtilClass {
    private static var theStage:Stage=null;
    public static function initialize(s:Stage):void {
        if (theStage) return; // we're initialized already
        theStage=s;
    }
    // once you call this, you can "trace(theStage)" and get correct output
    // other methods can also rely on theStage now.
}
```

Then you call `UtilClass.initialize(stage);` and you're set.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to go if the answer to the question above is **"not possible in AS-3"**.

Comment: You cannot initialize stage reference from the utility class *by itself*, you will anyway have to call the methods of that class from main code execution thread that starts in the `Main` sprite/MC instance that has access to stage. Also, putting code just outside methods won't compile if you'll address static vars/functions (IIRC I've seen a question here asking for this). So yes, the "bootstrap" of a standalone class to discover its environment is "**not possible in AS3**". It is to receive this information from outside.

Comment: Actually it compiles well _"putting code just outside methods won't compile"_ (see my edit) except you mean something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialise your UtilClass and pass the stage reference. I recommend you to have a Class only for 'manage' Stage reference.

You could try something like this (just a quick example):

```
public class StageReference
{
    public static const STAGE_DEFAULT:String = 'stageDefault';
    protected static var _stageMap:Dictionary;

    public static function getStage(id:String = StageReference.STAGE_DEFAULT):Stage
    {
        if (!(id in StageReference._getMap()))
            throw new Error('Cannot get Stage ("' + id + '") before it has been set.');

        return StageReference._getMap()[id];
    }

    public static function setStage(stage:Stage, id:String = StageReference.STAGE_DEFAULT):void
    {
        StageReference._getMap()[id] = stage;
    }

    public static function removeStage(id:String = StageReference.STAGE_DEFAULT):Boolean
    {
        if (!(id in StageReference._getMap()))
            return false;

        StageReference.setStage(null, id);

        return true;
    }

    protected static function _getMap():Dictionary
    {
        if (!StageReference._stageMap) StageReference._stageMap = new Dictionary();

        return StageReference._stageMap;
    }
}
```

When you start your application (Main Class or where you start to include your logic)

```
  StageReference.setStage(stage);
```

And when you need to get the stage reference

```
  trace('Checking the Stage: ', StageReference.getStage());
```